# How do I write bytes to stdin faster with ffmpeg for creating a new video with different frames

Tags: python, performance, ffmpeg, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I'm trying to speed up my code and what I'm trying to do is reading a video, converting it to a numpy array and the horizontally flipping each frame, and then writing the new frame to a new video. I've timed portions of my code and found that writing takes almost 4x more than reading. Is there a way to speed up my current implementation? I've also tried writing async code but that was also slower than sync code.

My implementation

```py
def without_compressed():
    video_path = '/tmp/test-video.mp4'

    cmd = ['ffprobe', '-v', 'error', '-select_streams', 'v:0', '-show_entries', 'stream=width,height', '-of', 'json', video_path]

    result = sp.run(cmd, capture_output=True, text=True)
    output = json.loads(result.stdout)

    resolution = output['streams'][0]
    width, height = resolution['width'], resolution['height']
    
    helpers.extract_audio_to_file(video_path,'new2.aac')

    process1 = (
    ffmpeg
    .input(video_path)
    .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24')
    .run_async(pipe_stdout=True)
    )

    process2 = (
        ffmpeg
        .input('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24', s='{}x{}'.format(width, height))
        .output('new2.mp4', pix_fmt='yuv420p')
        .overwrite_output()
        .run_async(pipe_stdin=True)
    )

    while True:
        in_bytes = process1.stdout.read(width * height * 3)
        if not in_bytes:
            break
        in_frame = (
            np
            .frombuffer(in_bytes, np.uint8)
            .reshape([height, width, 3])
        )
        out_frame = in_frame[:,::-1]
        # bottleneck
        process2.stdin.write(
            out_frame
            .astype(np.uint8)
            .tobytes()
        )

    process2.stdin.close()
    process1.wait()
    process2.wait()
```

When I run the program with `time python idea_ffmpeg.py`
[image]

With async

```py
video_path = '/tmp/test-video.mp4'

cmd = ['ffprobe', '-v', 'error', '-select_streams', 'v:0', '-show_entries', 'stream=width,height', '-of', 'json', video_path]

result = sp.run(cmd, capture_output=True, text=True)
output = json.loads(result.stdout)

resolution = output['streams'][0]
width, height = resolution['width'], resolution['height']
    



async def read_bytes(process1):
    
    return process1.stdout.read(width * height * 3)

async def write_bytes(out_frame,process2):
    
    process2.stdin.write(
            out_frame
            .astype(np.uint8)
            .tobytes()
        )

async def read_write_video(process1,process2):
    while True:
        task_read = asyncio.create_task(read_bytes(process1))
        in_bytes = await task_read
        if not in_bytes:
            break
        in_frame = (
            np
            .frombuffer(in_bytes, np.uint8)
            .reshape([height, width, 3])
        )
        out_frame = in_frame[:,::-1]
        await write_bytes(out_frame,process2)

async def async_ffmpeg():
    process1 = (
    ffmpeg
    .input(video_path)
    .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24')
    .run_async(pipe_stdout=True)
    )
    process2 = (
        ffmpeg
        .input('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24', s='{}x{}'.format(width, height))
        .output('new2.mp4', pix_fmt='yuv420p')
        .overwrite_output()
        .run_async(pipe_stdin=True)
    )

    await read_write_video(process1,process2)
    process2.stdin.close()
    process1.wait()
    process2.wait()


asyncio.run(async_ffmpeg())
```

When I run the program `time python idea_ffmpeg.py`
[image]

Comment: If flipping is exactly what you want to do (and not only dummy thing for reproducible example), then [you can do it with ffmpeg only](https://duxyng.wordpress.com/2013/04/07/rotateflip-video-with-ffmpeg/)